# Caching listview items when the user is offline

Tags: android, listview, caching

I am using Marvel api to get name, images and description, but I want the users to view it in offline mode too...How can I cache it apart from db system? Can Lru cache be used to do it? I just want to know the approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your marvel arrayList to db with the help of [**TinyDB**](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) in ACtivity `onPause()` CallaBack

```
ArrayList<Person> usersWhoWon = new ArrayList<Person>();
tinydb.putListObject("allWinners", usersWhoWon);
```

and then  in `onResume()` callaback check if user is offline and  fetch your marvel comic list from tinyDB

```
new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getListObject(
                    PreferenceHelper.MY_CART_LIST_LOCAL, Marvel.class)
```